# How to know what was clicked in a click event?

Tags: javascript

```
var list = document.createElement("div");
        list.classList.add("list");
        list.innerHTML = '<ul>'+
                        '<li class="on">'+
                            '<span>1</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                        '<li class="on">'+
                            '<span>2</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                        '<li>'+
                            '<span>3</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                        '<li>'+
                            '<span>4</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                        '<li>'+
                            '<span>5</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                    '</ul>';

list.addEventListener("click", function(e){
     //How to get the li I clicked
});
```

I created element as createElement and content as innerHTML. And I created a click event.
I am not sure how to get the li I clicked here.

Comment: try `console.log(e.target)`;

Comment: try `console.log(e)` and eplore it for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) property:

```js
var list = document.createElement("div");
        list.classList.add("list");
        list.innerHTML = '<ul>'+
                        '<li class="on">'+
                            '<span>1</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                        '<li class="on">'+
                            '<span>2</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                        '<li>'+
                            '<span>3</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                        '<li>'+
                            '<span>4</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                        '<li>'+
                            '<span>5</span>'+
                        '</li>'+
                    '</ul>';

list.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  console.log('clicked', e.target);
});

document.body.append(list);
```